# What's the proper way of redirecting HTTP response in c# web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, routes, response

Below is a sample response from our site.

HTTP Response Code is 404 (not found)

> {
>       "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:2425/Prefix/Controller?parameter=param1'.",
>       "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Controller' that matches the request." }

We should be able to modify the HTTP Response to 403 (Bad Request) since the user is returning incomplete parameters (there's another parameter, e.g. parameter2), which is also required, and we should also modify the message detail into something customizable.

Is this achievable?

Below is the sample method from WebApiConfig.cs

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
// Web API configuration and services
// Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

// Web API routes
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

I've tried removing config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(), but the application doesn't go to the controller if the parameters aren't matched, so I can return a response.

Answer (score 0):

you can create Middleware class where you can check and modify HTTP request data (parameters, headers, route, return status code end etc) before controller gets it and after controller execution. 
Here is [a good example](https://dotnetthoughts.net/build-your-first-asp-net-5-middleware/) of middleware